# Solatron giving incorrect value of capacitance

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, capacitance

So I'm conducting an experiment with an impedance analyzer (AD5933). But for the experiment, I need a calibration impedance. I am calculating this calibration impedance using a Solartron. I put 2 parallel copper plates ( 8100 sq mm, with spacing of 40 mm) in a setup ( I stuck the copper plates to teflon blocks) and calculated the capacitance using the Solartron. When I put nothing in between the copper plates (air as dielectric), the capacitance values give me a dielectric of 1.2-1.75. However, when I put water in between the 2 plates ( I put a plastic bag filled with water and also put the entire setup in de-ionised water), I get value of dielectric that no way corresponds to the 70-80 that I should be getting (since water has dielectric of 70-80). So for water as dielectric, I get 1nF, whereas I'm supposed to get 143pF (if you calculate it theoretically). This is at 30kHz.

I have repeated this experiment and even asked my supervisor, but no one seems to be able to know what the problem is. Has anyone had this issue or can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: So, what value did you get ?

Comment: So for water as dielectric, I get 1nF, whereas I'm supposed to get 143pF (if you calculate it theoretically). This is at 30kHz.

Comment: You should put this information in your original post as it then gives a more complete situation.

Comment: And you may find this relevant : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41115/why-is-water-not-used-as-a-dielectric-in-the-condenser

Comment: In other words, your water isn't pure enough, try measuring the resistance of your capacitor. Any conductivity will be interpreted as extra capacitance by a meter that expects neglible leakage current.

Comment: Its de-ionised water that i sourced from the electrochemistry lab. I cross-checked this twice. I even checked with a multimeter to make sure the water does not conduct.

Comment: A few things you should check: 1)90mm x 90mm plates 40mm apart are far from _close enough_ to be treated as borderless capacitor. 2)Air capacitance is approx 1.8pF, such low value are hard to measure with accuracy, strays can be same magnitude or greater 3)Such a capacitance yelds over 1Mohm reactance @ 30kHz, you may increase frequency.. 4)..but watch out for resonaces  4)Generally speaking, what is your measurement equip accuracy? Did you add up error propagation? 5)Do you split real and imaginary parts ok? 0) _dividi et impera_ Why not check a few know good low tolerance capacitors first?

Comment: Hi Carloc, I did actually check. Yes indeed, it should be 1.79pF. And my wires have a stray capacitance of 0.4pF ( this was confirmed by testing). And the value I get is 3.2pF. My range of measurement is 1kHz-100kHz. I will have to check the Solartron accuracy. The impedance analyser is AD5933. Real+imaginary is split up indeed (in the AD5933). I did check known capacitors and they seem to be quite okay. I checked with a 4.6pF cap and it gave a value of around 6pF, so I took this error into account.

Comment: Also try adding some resistance in parallel with known capacitor, so you ascertain accuracy with some real part too

Comment: hmm okay. but the issue is with the change of dielectric. So, with air as a dielectric, everything works. I set my calibration impedance to 1.8pF and I get the corresponding impedance in the results. Its only when I change this to water or anything else for that matter, it goes awry. I tried with wood today and the results were awry.